# How can I add a Python script at Ubuntu 11.10 startup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, python

What's the standard way of adding a python script to Ubuntu startup?

Comment: Do you want to run a script, or start a service?

Answer (score 2):

The absolute easiest way is to add an `@reboot` entry to your crontab with `crontab -e`:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot    /path/to/some/script.py
```

See `man 5 crontab` for more details on the crontab syntax.

Or you could instead write an upstart job and drop it in `/etc/init/`.